# React onChange not fired on controlled select field

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The following code seems correct but does not work as expected.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const Page = (props) => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0)

    const handleChange = () => {
        console.log(1)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSelectedValue(2)
        }, 1500)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <select onChange={handleChange} value={selectedValue}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
     )
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Page />,
    document.getElementById('pageRoot')
)
```

So when page loads after 1.5 seconds it selects the 2nd option but the onChange is not being fired since nothing is logged in console.

Comment: Do you expect onChange to fire by clicking options or you want it to fire automatically?

Comment: @onuriltan I want onChange to fire everytime the selected option is changed on drop down whether its programatically or user changing it manually.

Comment: I tried it in codeSandbox and it works expectedly [link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/hooks-demo-ononx)

Comment: @onuriltan I dont see anything being logged in console, do you? It only logs if you manually use the select drop down but on initial page load after 1.5 seconds nothing is logged even though the 2nd option is selected.

Comment: It prints one every time I select the unselected option, you can see the console tab below the presentation

Comment: But you did not use handleChange in useEffect hook, in useEffect hook you only used setSelectedValue which will just set the value not console log

Comment: @onuriltan yea that works fine but the issue is the initial page load when option is selected automatically. Refresh the page & wait 1.5 seconds, it will automatically select 2nd option but wont log anything. In useEffect I am setting the value of the status which changes the drop down value so shouldnt it trigger onChange event?

Comment: onChange event will only trigger if you click option that is not selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197230/discussion-between-onuriltan-and-ggio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the state programatically cannot trigger the `onChange` handler, otherwise we would find ourselves in an infinite loop with the following component:

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
    console.log(1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSelectedValue(2)
    }, 1500)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleChange} value={selectedValue}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`handleChange` triggers `setSelectedValue`, which triggers `handleChange`, which triggers `setSelectedValue` ...

So yes, setting the state programatically not triggering the `onChange` handler is expected behavior.

However, you can make sure to always go through a proxy, depending on what you want to achieve:

```
const Page = (props) => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0)

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setSelectedValue(newValue)
    console.log(1)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleChange(2)
    }, 1500)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)} value={selectedValue}>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing its because onchange occurs when the element loses focus, so while changing this programatically, on focus never occurs.